# Failed To Load vendor/autoload.php in Laravel App on shared hosting server

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I hosted laravel app on shared hosting server. I am using GuzzleHttp for third party request ....

> GuzzleHttp client require vendor/autoload.php file

so in my local system i have installed guzzlehttp using composer , and

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php'
```

is proper working on my local system . but when i uploaded code on shared hosting server and do composer install it gives me error :

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
>
> main(): Failed opening required
>   '../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear')

anyone please help me to solve this.

Comment: upload your vendor folder to server too

Comment: it is already there on server

Comment: Have you gave the permissions to the directory of storage and vendor as `775`?

Comment: yes , vendor folder has 755 permission

Comment: Try: `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update`

Comment: i have done `composer install` and `compose dump-autoload`   but got same error

Comment: Try this: `composer update --no-scripts`

Comment: still not working , got same error

Comment: We have do all possible stuffs, i suggest you to Rename/Delete vendor folder and then try to install it using `composer install / composer update` Hope it'll work for you!

Comment: ok i will try it , thanks for help

Comment: have you put public folder in root directory on hosting server?

Comment: yes , i have put public folder in root directory on hosting server